# English saying similar/equivalent to: "When you give, you receive twice as much."

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

In Greece we have a saying:

> If you give, you will receive twice as much.

Does an equivalent saying exist in English, and if so, what is it?

Comment: What comes around goes around?

Comment: You get back what you give out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you give, you will receive twice as much.

I think most English speakers would understand what you mean if you said it this way. I might phrase it as :

> What you give, you will receive [twofold](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/twofold).

to make the tone more like a [proverb](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/proverb).

I feel like there's a similar idiom in English but I can't recall the exact wording. The only thing that springs to mind is the [quote from Shakespeare's The Merchant of Venice about the quality of mercy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quality_of_mercy_(Shakespeare_quote)):

> it is twice blest;
>   It blesseth him that gives and him that takes:

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there is, "It is more blessed to give than to receive", which is a Bible quote. Not saying you'll get something back, though, just that it's the better thing to do.

There is, "You reap what you sow." You'll get back what you put out.

I can't think of anything specifically meaning the same as the saying you quote, I mean specifically the idea of getting back more than you gave. But that would hardly be surprising. I wouldn't assume that the same proverbial sayings would appear in every language.

Answer (score -1):

It is a perfectly common English saying:

*If you give, you will get back double.*

I have always heard it said with *get back* rather than *receive*. That has the nuance of emphasising the link between your giving and the return.

You don't need to look for something more complicated.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I've never heard that phrase before.  I've heard "You get out of life what you put into it" and I've heard Wiccans talk about "The law of threefold return" but never the above phrase.

Comment: There's nothing "unusual" about this suggestion, but I agree with @ssav that it's nowhere near a "saying". In fact, that exact text [*doesn't occur even **once***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+you+give+you+will+get+back+double%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) within the [*hundreds of billions*](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/) of words indexed by Google Books.

Comment: ...personally I wouldn't even call [*You get more than you give*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+get+more+than+you+give%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) a saying, but at least that one occurs 1460 times in print.